# Jquery Validate input fields onkeyup then perform function if button clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have searched everywhere but cannot seem to find the solution. I am trying to create a form in which it has 3 fieldsets with only one fieldset visible at a time. I have the onkeyup validation working as it appears like the following:

```
$("#contactInfoForm").validate({
        debug:true,
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
        firstName: {
           required: true,
           loginRegex: true,
           minlength: 2
        },
        lastName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        Email:{
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        Email_confirm:{
            required: true,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#Email"
        },
        streetAddressBilling:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        billingCity:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        state:{
            required: true
        },
        zip:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        phone:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3,
            phoneUS: true,
        },
        prefix:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        landline:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 4
        }
    },//end of rules
        groups: {
        DateofBirth: "phone prefix landline"
    },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "phone" || element.attr("name") == "prefix" || element.attr("name") == "landline") 
            error.insertAfter("#landline");
        else 
            error.insertAfter(element);
    },
        messages:{
        firstName: {
            required: "Please enter first name",
            lettersonly: "No numbers please",
            loginRegex: "Login format not valid",
            minlength: "Use at least 2 letters"
        },
        lastName: {
            required: "Please enter last name",
            lettersonly: "No numbers please",
            minlength: "Use at least 2 letters"
        },
        Email: {
            required: "Please enter your email",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        Email_confirm: {
            required: "Please enter your email",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            equalTo: "Email addresses do not match"
        },
        streetAddressBilling:{
            required: "Please enter your street address",
                minlength: "Use at least 3 letters"
        },
        billingCity:{
            required: "Please enter your city",
            minlength: "Use at least 3 letters"
        },
        state:{
            required: "Please select your state."
        },
        zip:{
            required: "Please enter your zip code",
            digits: "Please only use numbers",
            minlength: "Use at least 5 letters"
        },
        phone:{
            required: "Please enter your phone number",
            digits: "Please only use numbers",
            minlength: "Use 3 numbers"
        },
        prefix:{
            required: "Please enter your phone number",
            digits: "Please only use numbers",
            minlength: "Use 3 numbers"
        },
        landline:{
            required: "Please enter your phone number",
            digits: "Please only use numbers",
            minlength: "Use 4 numbers"
        }
    }//end of messages  
    });//end of contact info form validation rules
```

The next thing I am trying to do is have a continue button at the end of each fieldset. The button is supposed to check the forms in that fieldset and if they are validated, then open the next fieldset. Below is the HTML for a fieldset:

```
        <form onsubmit="return submitForm(this)" method="post" id="contactInfoForm" name="contactInfoForm" action="#">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="accessible-text">Address</legend>
        <ol>
          <li class="fullInput">
            <label id="caption_address1" for="address1">
              Address
            </label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" placeholder="Street Address" class="fullInput" maxlength="30" id="address1" name="address1">
          </li>
          <li class="no-label fullInput">
            <label class="accessible-text" id="caption_address2" for="address2">
              Billing Address Line 2
            </label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off" aria-required="false" placeholder="Street Address Line 2(Optional)" class="fullInput" id="address2" name="address2">
          </li>
          <li class="no-label">
            <label class="accessible-text" id="caption_city" for="city">
              City
            </label>
            <input type="text" aria-required="true" placeholder="City" maxlength="30" id="city" name="city">
          </li>
          <li class="no-label">
            <label class="accessible-text" id="caption_state" for="state">
              State
            </label>
            <select aria-required="true" class="required" name="state" id="state">
              <option value="">State</option>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li class="no-label">
            <label class="accessible-text" id="caption_zipCode" for="zipCode">
              ZIP
            </label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" placeholder="20151" name="zipCode" id="zipCode" maxlength="5">
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="fullInput" id="caption_phone" for="phone">
              Main Contact Number <a href="">Why we need this</a><br>
              <span class="accessible-text">Please enter your area code</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" placeholder="703" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="3">
            <label class="accessible-text" id="caption_prefix" for="prefix">
              Enter the next 3 numbers
            </label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" placeholder="555" name="prefix" id="prefix" maxlength="3">
            <label class="accessible-text" id="caption_landline" for="landline">
              Enter the last 4 numbers
            </label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" placeholder="5555" name="landline" id="landline" maxlength="4">
          </li>
        </ol>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Here is the JS for the button, I am using jquery ui for the fading:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(event){
    if($('#contactInfoForm').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: {
           required: true,
           loginRegex: true,
           minlength: 2
        },
        lastName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        Email:{
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        Email_confirm:{
            required: true,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#Email"
        },
        streetAddressBilling:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        billingCity:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        state:{
            required: true
        },
        zip:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        phone:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3,
            phoneUS: true,
        },
        prefix:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        landline:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 4
        }
    },//end of rules
    }))
{ //checks if it's valid
        if($(this).valid()) {
            $('#about_you_ver2').toggleClass("mod");
            $('#nameFieldsetEdit').toggleClass("hide");
            $('#name').fadeOut('xslow', function(){
                //$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
            }),
            $('#billing_address').fadeIn('xslow', function(){
                //$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
            }),
            $('#billing_container p').fadeIn('xslow', function(){
                //$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
            })
        }//end of valid direction
    }
    else{
        alert("I'm not valid");
    }
});//end of onclick for button
```

I am stuck at the point where the form passes validation when clicking the button without entering any information. How can  I accomplish this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have more code than I care to work with here, but I'll point out some of your mistakes and provide a simple demo.

- Regarding your `if($('#contactInfoForm').validate(` line.  `.validate()` is the plugin's *initialization*, not a method to call to test the form's validity.  Instead, `.validate()` should be called *once* within the DOM ready event handler.  Then once initialized, the form is tested automatically using its various built-in event handlers.  The form can also be tested programmatically using the `.valid()` method.
- You do not need a `click` handler.  The `click` event of the `submit` button is automatically captured by the plugin.
- Regarding your inline `onsubmit="return submitForm(this)"` code.  jQuery renders all inline JavaScript obsolete.  Not only that, it makes no sense to use an `onsubmit` when the `.validate()` plugin already has a perfectly good `submitHandler` built in.
- `onkeyup: false` will *disable* any live keystroke validation.  By default, the plugin will validate on every keystroke, so simply leave the option out of the initialization to keep the feature enabled.

Here is how I would structure a multi-step form with validation.

1)  Put each `<fieldset>` within its own unique set of `<form>` tags.

2)  Initialize `.validate()` separately on each `<form>`.  This way you can also logically organize the rules for each step within its own `.validate()` initialization function.

3)  Use the `submitHandler` callback within each instance of `.validate()` to hide the particular step upon successful validation and then reveal the next form.  The `submitHandler` only fires when the `form` is valid so a whole lot of your conditional code is rendered obsolete.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wqjnn/**

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform1">
    <h1>Step 1</h1>
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="submit" value="go to step 2" />
</form>

<form id="myform2">
    <h1>Step 2</h1>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" value="go to step 3" />
</form>

<form id="myform3">
    <h1>Step 3</h1>
    <input type="text" name="field3" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform1').validate({
        // your rules for step 1 fields,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).hide(function () { // hide this step
                $('#myform2').show();  // show step 2
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#myform2').validate({
        // your rules for step 2 fields,
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            $(form).hide(function () { // hide this step
                $('#myform3').show();  // show step 3
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#myform3').validate({
        // your rules for step 3 fields,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var data1 = $('#myform1').serialize();
            var data2 = $('#myform2').serialize();
            var data3 = $(form).serialize();
            var data = data1 + "&" + data2 + "&" + data3; // concatenate data from all forms
            // alert(data);
            // your ajax?
            return false; // to block normal form submit if needed
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt edits. This version is a valuable solution and may be my final answer. However, I am dealing with limitations that I do not always have the permission to change certain code (i.e. - onsubmit coding). I am trying to change this to a 3 form layout but right now I have to create a version with "continue" buttons that have a function to check only the forms in their relative fieldset that would then, if validated, perform more actions. Thank you for your help.